# Partial Derivative v/s Total Derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am bit confused regarding the geometrical/logical meaning of partial and total derivative. I have given my confusion with examples as follows

**Question**

1. Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)$ , then how do we write  the limit method of representing $ \frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial x} \text{and} \frac{\mathrm{d} f(x,y)}{\mathrm{d} x}$  at (a,b)? What is the difference?
2. Imagine I have a function $f(t,x,y)= t^4+x^2+y^3+2xy^9\tag 1$

   what could be $ \frac{\partial  f(t,x,y)}{\partial x} , \frac{\mathrm{d} f(t,x,y)}{\mathrm{d} x},\frac{\partial  f(t,x,y)}{\partial t} , \frac{\mathrm{d} f(t,x,y)}{\mathrm{d} t}$? What is the difference between them in meaning?
3. Imagine I have a function $f(t,x,y)= t^4+x^2+y^3+2xy^9,x=\psi(t),y=\tau(t)\tag 1$

   what could be $ \frac{\partial  f(t,x,y)}{\partial x} , \frac{\mathrm{d} f(t,x,y)}{\mathrm{d} x},\frac{\partial  f(t,x,y)}{\partial t} , \frac{\mathrm{d} f(t,x,y)}{\mathrm{d} t}$? What is the difference between them in meaning?
4. When we can say  $ \frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} f(x,y)}{\mathrm{d} x}$? Can we say  $\frac{\partial^2 f(t,x,y)}{\partial x dy} =\frac{\partial^2 f(t,x,y)}{ dy \partial x}$    if function $f(t,x,y)$  is $C^2$  continuous?
5. We have a function curve ${f(t,g_1,g_2,g_3)}_{3 \times 1} \tag 2$

   and we have a  $4 \times 1$ array  called $p=\begin{pmatrix}t\\ 
   g_1\\ 
   g_2\\ 
   g_3
   \end{pmatrix}$  All t and $g_i$ are variables, t is the curvilinear parameter . What is the meaning difference between $\frac{\partial f(t,g_1,g_2,g_3)}{\partial p} \text{and} \frac{d f(t,g_1,g_2,g_3)}{d p} $? How do we express the difference in limit notations?

NB : Replies written with  question enumeration will be more helpul. These are basics, I know. But I get confused some time. Looking for interpretations beyond equations. Means geometrically or logically coherent one.**This is not a homework problem**  just because it is simple. I made the example for expressing my issue so that I can learn from the result. Thanks for the time to read my question.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No No I just made example for expressing my problem..  You can see I am asking meaning than solution

Comment: A partial derivative answers the question, "At what rate does a function change given a change to one variable while holding all others (not dependent on it) constant?" A total derivative, however, answers the question, "At what rate does a function change given the individual rates of change of each variable and the specific amount they've been nudged?" In some cases, a Jacobian (vector of partial derivatives) is enough info. In others, you might want the total differential. (Which is just the sum of each Jacobian element scaled by the specific nudge to the corresponding variable.)

Answer (score 3):

As Paul said, the formal definition of a partial derivative is the limit $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)=\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)}{h}.$$

This definition must be interpreted as a slope of the tangent line at the point $(a,b)$ for the intersection curve between the plane $y=b$ and the surface $f(x,y)$.

Now, for functions of more than one independent variable $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ the sum of the partial differentials with respect to all of the independent variables is the total differential $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}dx_2+ \cdots +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}dx_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i.$$

Suppose that $f(t,x,y)$ with $x=\psi(t), \, y=\tau(t)$. Then we have $$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt},$$ since $\frac{dt}{dt}=1$ and $x'(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$ because the function $x(t)$ is a real valued function of a real variable

Answer (score 0):

1. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)=lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)}{h}$.  $\frac{d f}{d x}(a,b)$ has no meaning, unless $y$ is a function of $x$. I will address the other questions as I get some time.

Comment: I take it you didn't get around to the other questions

Comment: Correct, I retired.  Sorry for leaving you hanging.