# On an application of the chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential

Define a sequence $(\mathbf{y})_{i=0}^N$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:
$$\mathbf{y}_{k+1} = \mathbf{y}_{k} + \lambda \nabla_\mathbf{y} E(\mathbf{y}_k,\mathbf{w}), \quad k=0,1,\ldots,N-1,$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant, $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $E:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to \mathbb{R}$ is some differentiable function.

Let $Q:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and $L=Q(\mathbf{y} _N)$.

Applying the chain rule we have:
$$\frac{dL}{d\mathbf{w}} = \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{\partial \mathbf{y}_k^\top}{\partial \mathbf{w}} \frac{dQ}{d\mathbf{y}_k}\qquad (1)$$
and
$$\frac{dQ}{d\mathbf{y}_k} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{y}_{k+1}^\top}{\partial \mathbf{y}_{k}} \frac{dQ}{d\mathbf{y}_{k+1}}.\qquad (2)$$

(Source: [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v22/domke12/domke12.pdf), equation (12))

My questions:

1. How to obtain $(1)$? Shouldn't it be 
   $$\frac{dL}{d\mathbf{w}} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{d\mathbf{y}_k^\top}{d\mathbf{w}} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial\mathbf{y}_k}?$$ The operators $\partial$ and $d$ seem to be reversed.
2. I'm again confused about using $\partial$ and $d$ in $(2)$. Could you please explain it?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think they should all be $\partial$, not $d$.

For example, [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) and [tensor calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) *usually* just use $\partial$, I think.

So at least for the two equations you show, Domke is using $d$ for vector derivatives of multivariate scalar functions and $\partial$ otherwise. 
This sort of makes sense, since you can treat it like 1D function of single variable (that happens to be a vector).
However, this pattern is broken in other sections of the paper.

On the other hand, the form you suggest is more like the classic chain rule (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566376/derivation-of-the-multivariate-chain-rule?noredirect=1&lq=1)). However, you can also write the chain rule as all $\partial$ (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions)).

But to be honest, they are interchangeable here I think. It only really matters when you need to differentiate between many different types of derivatives (e.g. partial, total, covariant, Lie, exterior, ...) [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209241/exterior-derivative-vs-covariant-derivative-vs-lie-derivative/1237112),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145617/lie-vs-covariant-derivative-visual-motivation),[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/intuitive-explanation-of-covariant-contravariant-and-lie-derivatives)]. There is a notion of total vs partial derivative (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920665/partial-derivative-v-s-total-derivative?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715751/partial-vs-total-derivative-basic?rq=1)), but it doesn't seem to be what's meant here.